# What are projections from $A \times B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This question has come up on an assignment for an online class I'm taking. I don't want the answer, but the question is not in our material at all (I've taken extensive notes). The teachers are hard to get a hold of, and their responses are never that helpful.

Can someone perhaps tell me what this question is talking about? Or refer me to a theorem or area I need to read up on?

Thank you!

> Let   $A = \{2, 3, 5\}$ and $B = \{x, y\}$.
>
> Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be the projections of $A \times B$ onto the
>   first and second coordinates.
>
> That is, for each pair $(a, b) \in A \times B,\ p_1(a, b) = a$ and $p_2(a, b) = b$.
>
> Find $p_2(2, y)$ and $p_2(5, x)$. What is the range of $p_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to know to answer this question.

**First**, you need to know what $A \times B$ means.  If $A$ is a set and $B$ is a set, then $A \times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$, where the first element $x$ belongs to $A$ and the second element $y$ belongs to $B$.

So, for example, if $A = \{socks, shoes \}$ and $B = \{apple, orange, banana \}$ then $$A \times B = \{ (socks, apple), (socks, orange), (socks, banana), (shoes, apple), (shoes, orange), (shoes, banana) \}$$

**Second**, you need to know what *projection onto the first coordinate* means.  "Projection onto the first coordinate" (denoted $p_1$ here) is a function that takes an ordered pair like $(x,y)$ and just strips away everything but the first coordinate.  So $p_1(candy, rhubarb) = candy$.  Likewise $p_2(candy, rhubarb) = rhubarb$.

Does the question make sense now?

Comment: Yes, I think so! I had assumed I needed to do actually do something with "Find p2(2,y)" other than it literally just being y. I guess I was overthinking it. So, the range of p2 = {x,y}.

Comment: @BarryCooper  Yes, exactly.